# Small battery for multiple small charges

Tags: batteries

What are small batteries that can put up with lots of small charges?

I get that you can't have everything in a design, so I get that it will be heavy or expensive.

Imagine a RC car with some photo-voltaic cells. Car would have irregular exposure to light and could charge such battery.

Comment: Supercapacitors?

Comment: `small battery` ... is that anything under 2 kilograms?

Comment: @jsotola I consider a 2kg battery to be enormous.

Comment: You need to define "small battery" and "small charges".  In engineering units, please.  My "small battery" may weigh more than a truck -- yours may weigh less than a penny.  My "small charge" may be three electrons -- yours may be enough energy to power Los Angeles for a year.

Comment: @TimWescott: consider something that could be used in a RC to car. <0.5kg.

Comment: update your question with a clear description of the battery

Comment: Also provide the purpose of the vehicle, purpose of this recharging, and purpose of the battery. This sounds like an XY problem to me because it sounds misguided and I see very few ways in which the described charging scenario is viable. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Consider a garden light barely drives a 20mA LED for a few hours after being charged all day, with a small battery, using a PV panel that is about 100x bigger than the LED ----try again with real datasheets.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree with Elliot Alderson. supercapacitors would probably suit your needs the best. If the main source of charging are photo-voltaic cells, which will produce a varying voltage (depending on the light), then super-caps are by far the easiest to design with.

According to an [article](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/whats_the_role_of_the_supercapacitor) by Battery University, it says that "supercapacitor[s], rated in farads, which is thousands of times higher than the electrolytic capacitor. The supercapacitor is **used for energy storage undergoing frequent charge and discharge cycles at high current and short duration**"

An RC car will require high amounts of current at certain times while taking no current at others. As well, a super-capacitor can tolerate the continuous pulses of high current needed to power the RC car. As long as the RC car is small enough and does not require too much current, I think the idea of powering it with supercapacitors is feasible. Now, I do not know who long you could run the RC car on a supercapacitor, but as long as it is pretty sunny, the idea remains mainly feasible.

Now there is an issue on how one could charge the supercapacitor while also drawing current for the RC car. You could solve this by either having two supercapacitors and switching in between, one that gets charged and another that supplies power to the RC car, and when one of them gets drained, you switch. This would require complex circuitry, but yet again is feasible.

Comment: Compare the Joules/cc and Joules/gram of a supercap and a LiIon battery.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean, but then again I doubt how well a Li-Ion battery can charge from sporadic amounts of energy coming from the photo-voltic cells. Maybe a hybrid between the two?

Comment: As far as I know a LiIon can handle charging at low currents, although managing the charge termination would be challenging.  I think that managing charge termination with sporadic current would be challenging too, however.  You'd want a super-efficient MPPT gizmo for extracting energy from the solar cell.

Comment: If an RC is what is going to be designed, I doubt an MPPT should be added in. Assuming that this is a small car, such as a toy RC car, then the MPPT would draw a considerable amount of current. The payoff would be more light hitting the solar cells but I doubt that payoff would help the in long run. Now I could see how a Li-Ion cell could be used, but like what I mentioned earlier, the varying currents would be hard to address.

Comment: @KevinYang Are you confusing MPPT (a purely electronic device) with a solar tracking system (i.e. motorized solar panel that turns to face the sun)?

Comment: @Hearth It seems I have.

Comment: @KevinYang your concern about power draw isn't unfounded, though -- you'd want to choose a simple MPPT algorithm that could run slowly on a low-power micro.  If you had a panel as big as a house (even a small house) you wouldn't need to sweat the efficiency of the processor nearly as much.

Answer (score 0):

> What are small batteries that can put up with lots of small charges?

Most rechargeable batteries are quite happy taking lots of small charges, so long as the charge current is not too high and the total charge doesn't exceed the battery's capacity. Nicad and MiMH batteries can withstand overcharging if the current is 1/10 the battery capacity or less. Lead-acid and Lithium based batteries have a voltage limit that must not be exceeded, and if they reach it the charge current must be reduced.

In the comments you suggest a 'small' battery would weigh less than 0.5kg. [Here](https://www.mrpositive.co.nz/giant-power-2s-7-4v-4200mah-35c-round-hardcase/) is a typical battery used in a modern 1/10th scale RC car. It is a 2 cell (7.4V) Lithium-Polymer type with capacity of 4.2Ah, and weighs 245g. This battery can be charged at up to 4.2A, but will also accept and hold charge at much lower current. The voltage on this battery must kept at or below 8.40V (4.20V per cell) while charging, and it must never be discharged below 6.0V.

If for example you had a 9V 3W solar panel the charge current in full sunlight would be ~0.33A, well below the maximum permitted for this battery. However you must use a charging circuit which limits the maximum voltage to 8.4V. At this current a LDO (Low Drop Out) linear regulator set to output 8.4V would do the job.

Comment: If not terminating charge then Vmax < 4.2V cell is required to prevent early demise.

Comment: The sun only stays up for half a day so the battery won't be 'on charge' forever. Certainly the battery's lifespan will be shortened if kept fully charged, but if the car is driven... More likely you will have trouble getting enough charge into it for a reasonable run time. And of course the battery should be disconnected when not in use.

Comment: I'm extremely aware of what can be expected from solar input - as you are probably aware. || LiIon is immensely sensitive to trickle charging at Vmax. If a solar charger can achieve eg 0.33A/4.2A = C/12 when charged I'd expect noticeable permanent damage in hours to days. On some random day the damage may become complete and permanent with a 'vent with flame incident. Under trickle charge Lithium will plate out and ... . || Disconnection when not in use is 'fine enough' but a very bad way to guarantee battery safety when it is extremely easy to allow technology to do it for you.